# How to handle displaying, searching, and filtering large volumes of images in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, image, uicollectionview

I have a webservice that acts as a form of a digital asset manager.  Some of our users have THOUSANDS of images stored in their account.  We want to give them an iPhone app that lets them access these images.  We can use infinite scroll but we would like some form of a table of uicollectionview segmented by dates with a side index list that they can scroll through and jump to.  To do that we would need to download ALL of their images into a collectionview, which seems insane.

How do others handle displaying, searching and filtering large volumes of images?

Comment: Asynchronous loading; an index of the data using small thumbnails & only loading individual larger images once requested; determining how many images fit on screen at once & only keeping around that many + some buffer; caching downloads to a point; removing images from memory as needed. BTW a tableview/collection view is still essentially "infinite scroll," even if there's a sidebar index or subsection headers, but you certainly don't want to load everything at once or you'll quickly find it becomes unresponsive and prone to crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Typically when large amounts of data needs to be downloaded from a web service (or filesystem) the key is not to do it all at once, but to partition it into manageable pieces which you load and unload as needed. There is no one way to do this, but that is the general idea.

To manage this process it can be helpful to download a complete index  that describes all the content (like a json list of image urls) without downloading every image or piece of data in the database (but not necessary - this won't work with millions of entries). This allows you to search and navigate through content without requiring huge downloads.

In your question it sounds like your images are grouped somewhat by date ranges. A possible procedure you could explore could be something like:

1. Download an index of all images with their associated dates and load this into memory. (In the thousands this should be no problem).

   ```
   images : [
      {
         url: "http://someurl/image.png",
         name: "Great Image!", 
         date: "12/3/15"
         // possibly include more data like search tags...
      },..
   ]
   ```
2. Begin downloading the initial set of images associated with most recent date range and display them as they complete.
3. When the user selects a new date range or scrolls of the page, show placeholder image tiles in the collection view. Start downloading the new images asynchronously and display them as they arrive.
4. Unload images from the previous date range from memory. (You could keep a cache in the filesystem).
5. Repeat as the visible area changes.

On iOS I usually use AFNetworking (Or AlamoFire for Swift) to handle asynchronous network requests.

Comment: Excellent answer. How would I unload images?

Comment: @JoshL Are you referring to the actual code of telling an image to unload? Or deciding when to unload?

Comment: @JoshL You could unload them as soon as you load a new tab, or scroll a certain distance away, you could try a lot of things. For the actual code, if you are using ARC Objective-C or Swift, objects are released when there are no longer any references to them or for manual memory [image release];

Comment: I suggest saving a certain number (or certain size) of images locally. We implemented our own cache that expired images after a certain time period. There are several open source caches that can help: http://cocoa.tumblr.com/post/118790665043/tmcache-is-no-longer-being-actively-maintained

Comment: @EricS I agree a local file cache for downloaded images is a good idea for fast loading/unloading and saving bandwidth.